# navfn compile error

Tags: ros, compile, ros-kinetic, navfn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ,
for writing my own global planner, i cloned source of navigation stack

git clone https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.git

i copied navfn package to my own workspace and built with catkin_make but this weird error comes;

```
/home/largo/ws/src/navfn/src/navfn_node.cpp: In member function ‘void navfn::NavfnWithCostmap::poseCallback(const ConstPtr&)’:
/home/largo/ws/src/navfn/src/navfn_node.cpp:85:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS::getRobotPose(geometry_msgs::PoseStamped&)’
   cmap_->getRobotPose(global_pose);
```

I had built this package before with the same steps!!!

Any help will be appreciated.

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301392/navfn-compile-error/) by [zeynep](https://answers.ros.org/users/28278/zeynep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2018-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you only copy the one package to your workspace? You probably want to build the whole navigation stack from a consistent version. Also -- pay attention to which branch you are using -- we've made a lot of API changes in the melodic-devel branch (the default branch when cloning). If you are on Kinetic, you want to "git checkout kinetic-devel" within the git repo to get the right version.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2018-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zeynep](https://answers.ros.org/users/28278/zeynep/) on 2018-08-23**:
thank you very much,
you are right, it is because of the wrong branch, i use kinetic but cloned melodic-devel branch